# Эмуляция веб камеры

Tags: c#, видео

Вопрос следующий: как реализовать виртуальную веб-камеру, которую приложения (Skype, к примеру) определяли как обычную камеру. И чтобы была возможность транслировать на неё картинку из C# кода? Возможно уже есть готовые библиотеки. Если да, ткните, пожалуйста, носом, ибо я не нашёл. Заранее благодарен всем ответившим.

Comment: Хм. Написать свой драйвер, который бы определялся как драйвер вебкамеры, но выдавал бы заранее определённый видеопоток/статичную картинку?

Comment: драйвер напиши чтобы его воспринимало как железо

Answer (score 1):

Как временный вариант, можешь скачать [ManyCam](https://manycam.com/). Она может создавать виртуальную веб-камеру, чтобы её видели приложения как обычную камеру. Сама виртуальная вебка способна показывать почти всё, что угодно, будь это изображение с другой камеры, будь это игра, будь это просто экран монитора...

В общем, там всё увидишь. Сейчас сам использую приложение для проекта на Unity. Её бесплатная версия несколько ограниченна, но если срочно нужна виртуальная веб-камера - пока можешь воспользоваться ManyCam.

Comment: Если есть вопросы по программке - задавайте.